# Received the ash elite skin from outbreak packs

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

After Operation Chimera hit Rainbow Six Siege they said people will get the ash elite skin. I think no body got it.

I got 4 outbreak packs. And luckily I got the Ash elite skin from the outbreak packs. Now if people will get the ash elite skin will my skin that I received from the outbreak pack removed?

*Will my elite skin get removed with the new one that we are suppose to receive?*

Comment: As you can clearly see that person said he didn't receive the packs and the elite skin. Please read the question carefully

Comment: Og yeah sorry, i totaly misread that

Comment: For clarity, I voted to close not as a dupe, but as developer intent -- this isn't really something we can feasibly know for sure.

Comment: I mean we both asked different questions... How is it a posibble duplicate???

Comment: I totally asked another question Thats no dupe

Comment: While I'm not totally convinced these are duplicates, @Schism has the right idea; we have no way of knowing what will be done in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the first skin you got wont disappear You ll just have different elite ash skin One with camo one without it

Hope this Helps

Comment: So do you mean that I will have two different skins in the uniform selection section?

Comment: Yeah You will !!